# Missing $ error <inserted>

Tags: errors, text

I have a problem with LaTeX...

I'm writing simple text in a `\section{Goals}`, with no math forumulas, no code, ogni text...

This is my LaTeX code:

```
\section{Goals}
\labelsec{Goals}
Abbiamo già accennato nell'introduzione che uno degli 
obiettivi di questo elaborato è quello di focalizzarsi 
sullo sviluppo del software Model Driven a partire dalla 
primissima fase, di verifica dei requisiti, così da..
```

And when I do quick compile, LaTeX gave me

> Missing $ error.

But, if I have only

```
\section{Goals}
\labelsec{Goals}
Abbiamo già accennato nell'introduzione che uno degli 
obiettivi di questo elaborato è quello di focalizzarsi 
sullo sviluppo del software Model Driven a partire dalla 
primissima fase, di verifica dei requisiti
```

I don't have the error. Why? I don't understand why `, così da` gives me the error!

This is the entire code of the latex document:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{manifest}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Esame finale A.A. 2016/2017\\
 Ingegneria dei Sistemi Software}

\maketitle

    \section{Goals}
    \labelsec{Goals}
    Abbiamo già accennato nell'introduzione che uno degli 
obiettivi di questo elaborato è quello di focalizzarsi 
sullo sviluppo del software Model Driven a partire dalla
primissima fase, di verifica dei requisiti così da

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  [This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a118cf28e9bbb298fc43246b5d44f353) works without a problem.

Comment: Please add a complete MWE from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` in order to be able to help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Also, if you downvote, please don't forget to revert the vote after the question is improved.

Comment: @HenriMenke it really isn't hard to reproduce given the code in the question, see my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This was before the MWE.

Comment: @HenriMenke No I answered before the question was edited.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have not provided a full example but I would guess that you have

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\section{Goals}
\label{Goals}
Abbiamo già accennato nell'introduzione che uno degli 
obiettivi di questo elaborato è quello di focalizzarsi 
sullo sviluppo del software Model Driven a partire dalla 
primissima fase, di verifica dei requisiti, così da..
\end{document}
```

which produces the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 ...ima fase, di verifica dei requisiti, così
                                                   da..
?
```

The reason is that the encoding has been incorrectly specified as `latin1` when your file is in `UTF-8` If you declare `[utf8]` then

[image]

Why a math error? Well in UTf-8 non ascii characters take multiple bytes and `ì` takes 2, the bytes hex C3 AC . In latin1 encoding that you specified, each character takes a single byte so C3 AC is seen as two characters.

C3 is `\~A`

and

AC is `\lnot` which is a math operator seen here in text mode so generates the error.

Comment: I changed my usepackage from
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and now it works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a bit of guess, as you didn't post a MWE (Minimal Working Example).

I guess, that you missed to define the encoding used in your input file.  I therefore added `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or in my case `luainputenc`.

At least, this MWE is working for me.

But as there is so much guess (e.g. I also removed the `\labelsec`-command, as I don't know, where it comes from.  Maybe this is the root of your problem?  Who knows.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\begin{document}
\section{Goals}
\label{Goals}
Abbiamo già accennato nell'introduzione che uno degli 
obiettivi di questo elaborato è quello di focalizzarsi 
sullo sviluppo del software Model Driven a partire dalla 
primissima fase, di verifica dei requisiti, così da..
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there any particular reason for suggesting luainputenc here? it's a rather specialised package and certainly not recommended for most luatex documents.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am nowadys working with lualatex, as I have to include OTF fonts in my daily work.  I the time, when I switched from  pdflatex to lualatex, I had some warnings and errors, when I used normal inputenc with lualatex.  The errors vanished, as soon, as I switched to luainputenc. So my emacs now includes it as part of my daily template to be inserted, whenever I open a new, non existing file.  Why is it not recommended?

Comment: For the question the OP clearly was not using luatex so a luatex answer isn't clearly desirable here but luainputenc is useful for accessing classic 8bit fonts in tex encodings with luatex but largely disables most other luatex access to opentype font features as it requires passing characters through the classic tex ascii LICR representation as used for inputenc (or at least that is its default behaviour as used here) You should only consider using if converting pdftex documents using legacy font packages.